# Question on Product Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is it true that for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$,  $(Y,\mathcal{G},\nu)$, if $f$ is a ($\mathcal{F} \times \mathcal{G}$)-measurable function on $X \times Y$, then

$$\int |f(x,y)| \, d\mu(x) \leq ||\,f||_2 $$ for a.e. $y \in Y$
and
$$\int |f(x,y)| \, d\nu(y) \leq ||\,f||_2 $$ for a.e. $x \in X$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general this is not true. Take for example, $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Lebesgue measure.

Then your question is whether the following holds for all (nice enough) $f$:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x,y)| dx\le \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|^2 dx\right)^{1/2}$$

for almost all $y\in\mathbb{R}$. You can see that this can't be right by a scaling argument. For $\lambda>0$, replace $f$ by $f_\lambda(x)=f(\lambda x)$, then we would have

$$\frac{1}{\lambda} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x,\lambda y)| dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_\lambda(x,y)| dx\le \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_\lambda(x)|^2 dx\right)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{\lambda^{1/2}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|^2 dx\right)^{1/2}$$

The powers of $\lambda$ don't match up. So we can normalize $f$ properly and pick $\lambda$ really small so that the LHS will be much larger than the RHS.

Comment: I was working on a problem and I headed in the wrong direction as first.Thanks for the prompt response.